# how to create absolute path from absolute and relative one?

Tags: java, kotlin, java-nio

I write a simple application on kotlin and I encountered the next problem:

I have relative (`../../`) and absolute (`a/b/c`) paths. I want to get path `a/` . How to accomplish that without dancing with strings? Maybe there are methods in java/kotlin which allow to do it?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you target the JVM. Also, please note `a/b/c` is **not** an absolute path.

In Java we can process paths using the [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) class. Merging two paths is performed by `resolve()` method and removing redundant parts like `..` is called the "path normalization":

```kotlin
val base = Path.of("a/b/c")
val path = base.resolve("../../").normalize()
println(path) // prints: a
```